# jQuery jstree, pre-expanding/loading a subset of nodes based on ids

Tags: jquery, ajax, jstree

Here is my scenario.  I have a rather large multi-tier tree that I don't want to load the entire tree at initial creation, however I want to be able to expand specific nodes/tree branch path based on supplied node id(s).

The problem is when I attempt to expand child nodes of a tree branch whose parent has not completed loading, the node does not get the open_node event properly.

So I was wondering if anyone has come up with a process where a tree can traverse/expand a tree path through multiple levels where the child open_node event is called once the parent node/level has completed loading.

Comment: How can you try to open child if parent hasn't finished (ajax) loading?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post but if someone stumbles upon it, like I did today, looking for an answer to the exact same question then here is a link to my question which has an answer:

[Programatically expanding nodes in jstree with ajax load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952653/programatically-expanding-nodes-in-jstree-with-ajax-load/14957226#14957226)